# Autocomplete for password doesn't work for my webapp (in firefox)

Tags: html, autocomplete, passwords

I've created a login submit form in HTML but for some reason autocompletion does not work in firefox.

This is what happens in Firefox:
- I give username and password and click on the login button
- Firefox prompts me if I would like to remember the password. I press 'remember' and login works.
- I log out and return to the login page. I would expect the username and password field to be prefilled but that is not the case. Notice that I don't (want to) use cookies.

Here's the code for this page:

```
<form name="login_form" id="login_form" autocomplete="ON" onsubmit="javascript:xajax_action_login(document.getElementById('user_name').value, document.getElementById('password').value); return false;">
    <div class="login_line">
        <div class="login_line_left">name</div>
        <div id="user_name_id" class="login_line_right"><input size="16" maxlength="16" name="user_name" id="user_name" type="text"></div>
    </div> <!-- login_line -->
    <div class="login_line">
        <div class="login_line_left">password</div>
        <div id="password_id" class="login_line_right"><input size="16" maxlength="16" name="password" id="password" type="password"></div>
    </div> <!-- login_line -->
    <div class="login_line">
        <div class="login_line_left">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="login_line_right"><input class="button" value="login" type="submit"></div>
    </div> <!-- login_line -->
</form> <!-- login_form -->
```

What is wrong with my code? How can I get autocompletion to work in FF with my code?

Autocompletion does work correct with for instance gmail. Each time I visit the login page of gmail, the email and password fields are correctly prefilled. I don't use the 'remember me on this computer' checkbox so no cookies are used.

**Update** I'm using php and FF3

Thanks,
Jasper

Comment: I am using FF3 and it works for me. I have used your example and put it in a ASPX form and it's ok.

Comment: Does it make any difference if you use an action="..." instead of the onsubmit?

Comment: Hi Netadictos. Can you explain what you mean by 'put it in a ASPX form'? The html code contains a form which is usually in the body of an html page.

Comment: Hi Divideandconquer. I also tried this form with an extra action=.. but not without the onsubmit. It shouldn't make any difference... Besides I want the form to call a js function and I don't think it is possible with an action=..

Comment: Jasper, next time don't make a duplicate question.  Ask once and stick with it.

Answer (score 2):

Does your login URL include a session ID that changes each time?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your saved passwords list to see if you have already told Firefox to **never remember** credentials for your site?

Answer (score 1):

> Firefox prompts me if I would like to remember the password. I press 'remember' and login works. - I log out and return to the login page. I would expect the username and password field to be prefilled

That's not the way Firefox works. You have to put the username in, and it will remember the password *for that username*.

Answer (score 0):

I pasted your HTML into an empty HTML document, removed the `onsubmit=""` javascript code,  typed in a username and password and hit submit, got prompted to save the password, and the next time I hit reload - FF3 autofilled both fields.

WorksForMe(tm).

I wonder if removing the `onsubmit=""` code changes anything for you...?

Also a link to a running example would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I found out why it doesn't work. I use ajax to paste the example html in a container div. Apperently firefox is very sensitive about this because (as mentioned before) my code does work in IE.