# autocomplete user/password in firefox

Tags: html, firefox, autocomplete, passwords

I've created a login submit form in HTML but for some reason user/password autocompletion does not work like I expect in firefox.

This is what happens in Firefox:

- I give username and password and click on the login button
- Firefox prompts me if I would like to remember the password. I press 'remember' and login works. (I made sure I deleted all remembered passwords before running this test)
- I log out and return to the login page. I would expect the username and password field to be prefilled but that is not the case (if FF has stored only one user/pw combi for a specific URL than it automatically prefills this combi in your form)

Notice that I don't (want to) use cookies. I verified in FF password manager that username and password had actually been stored (they were)

Here's the code for this page:

```
<form name="login_form" id="login_form" autocomplete="ON" onsubmit="javascript:xajax_action_login(document.getElementById('user_name').value, document.getElementById('password').value); return false;">
    <div class="login_line">
        <div class="login_line_left">name</div>
        <div id="user_name_id" class="login_line_right"><input size="16" maxlength="16" name="user_name" id="user_name" type="text"></div>
    </div> <!-- login_line -->
    <div class="login_line">
        <div class="login_line_left">password</div>
        <div id="password_id" class="login_line_right"><input size="16" maxlength="16" name="password" id="password" type="password"></div>
    </div> <!-- login_line -->
    <div class="login_line">
        <div class="login_line_left"> </div>
        <div class="login_line_right"><input class="button" value="login" type="submit">
    </div> <!-- login_line -->
</form> <!-- login_form -->
```

What is wrong with my code? How can I get autocompletion to work in FF with my code?

Autocompletion does work correct with for instance gmail. Each time I visit the login page of gmail, the email and password fields are correctly prefilled. I don't use the 'remember me on this computer' checkbox so no cookies are used.

I would greatly appriciate your help.
Jasper

**Update**
Autocomplete is enabled in firefox. I want to stay IE compatible.

Comment: The question seems to be an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311389/autocomplete-for-password-doesnt-work-for-my-webapp-in-firefox

Comment: This thread is an exact duplicate of [Autocomplete for password doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311389/autocomplete-for-password-doesnt-work-for-my-webapp-in-firefox).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out why it doesn't work. I use ajax to paste the example html in a container div. Apperently firefox is very sensitive about this because (as mentioned before) my code does work in IE.

Answer (score 1):

Are the urls static or dynamic, auto completion doesn't work with dynamic urls,
 say your url is:

```
http://www.domain.come/login.php?someDynamicVarLikeAdateOrSo=12312
```

Then password saving won't work, you should then use modrewrite or something to display the url as static to the browser

Answer (score 0):

First, check to see if autocomplete is enabled in firefox.
Then try setting the 'type' attribute of the text box to be 'autocomplete'. Details are given [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/textbox_(Firefox_autocomplete))

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have `autocomplete="ON"` in the `<form>` tag. Try changing that to `autocomplete="on"` -- that is, remove the capitalization of 'ON'.

Comment: Hi genehack, tried it and it didn't fix my problem. Thanks for your suggestion.